# Setting up remote Sublime Text build system

Tags: python, sublimetext3, build-system

I need help setting up a remote build system.

The build system I have below calls python on remote server but the issue is the file path.

I have the remote server mapped to my W: drive so when I call the build system it executes.

```
python W:\path\to\script.py
```

It needs to execute

```
python /home/me/path/to/script.py instead.
```

What i want to do is replace "\" for "/" and "W:" for "/home/me/"

```
{
"shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Remote Python",
        "shell_cmd": "C:/Users/me/Documents/Common/Putty/plink -v -l myName -pw myPass 192.168.0.10 python \"${file}\"",
    }
]
```

}

I have tried combinations of [Build System Variables](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#build-system-variables) but with no luck.

I have also hard-coded the "/home/me" part but i still need access to the other folders ie) "path/to/".

I believe the answer will involve the use of "sed" but I cannot get it working...

Answer (score 2):

Building on @MattDMo's answer, I got this working by using two capture groups: one to replace the drive letter (W:) with the project path (/home/me) and another to replace the backslashes with forward slashes. I noticed that the build window was not showing the delimiters properly, but the console was.

```
\"${file/(W:)|(\\\\)/(?1\\/home\\/me)(?2\\/)/g}\"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PCRE [regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)-based [substitutions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions) and [format strings](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html) in build system variables. So, instead of

```
\"${file}\"
```

in your `plink` command, use the following:

```
\"${file/w:/\/home\/me/i}\"
```

Sublime automatically changes the path delimiters from `\` to `/`, so we don't have to worry about that. All we need to do is find `w:` and replace it with `/home/me` (the `/` characters are escaped as `/` is also used to separate the different parts of the regex). The `i` at the end is the case-insensitive flag, so it'll work with both `w:` and `W:`.

I don't have access to a Windows box at the moment to test this, but it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes! However I do not (completely) agree that path delimiters are automatically changed. 
Using your answer sublime is calling "pathtoscript.py"
In other words the paths delimiters and the "W:" are being dropped.

I did some extra escaping and got \"${file/w:/\\\\home\\\\me/i}\" which calls homemepathtoscript.py but still no path delimiter.